# Snakebite HDFS touchz not working

Tags: python, hadoop, hdfs, snakebite

I want to use snakebite to check if a file exist in hdfs directory, and create if it doesnt exist. I'm following the documentation on `touchz` [here](http://snakebite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client.html) and using it like this:

```
def createFile(client):
    if client.test("/user/test/sample.txt", exists=True):
        print "file exists"
    else:
        print "file not exist, create file"
        print client.touchz(["/user/test/sample.txt"])

client = Client(remote_host, 8020, use_trash=False)        
createFile(client)
```

But when I go to check, I dont see sample.txt in `remote_host:/user/test/`
But I see the file when I used `hadoop fs -touchz remote_host:/user/test/sample.txt`

How to use snakebite's `touchz` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

snakebite's `touchz` yields a generator that doesn't do anything until you iterate over the values.

So you either have to iterate over the return value of `touchz` or call `list()` on it.